# No high on CS while writing to SD-Card with FatFs

Tags: pic, xc8, fatfs

I am hard struggling to set up my PIC project, with a SD card, that uses FatFs. I simulate it in Proteus - but during the full writing process, there is no high on the CS line from the SD card.
The other works. I already checked the pin configuration, spi works, and I used the the example code for the writing routine from an web example.
And sometimes i get the error CMD63 unsupported.
Has anybody an idea, why the CS is not high??

Answer (score 0):

To check:

1. Your pin is in analog mode
2. Check the TRIS register, your pin is as output
3. Check the datasheet if your pin can actually be actively driven. On some device, some pin can only be "pull down".
4. Try to add a 10k pullup resistor on the line.